# Subsetting columns with apply function in R using multiple criteria

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, apply

I can accomplish my subsetting in two actions, but would like to learn how to do it in one.

I want to keep all rows and exclude columns that are all NAs and exclude rows that are all zeros.

Example:

```
x1 <- 1:10
x2 <- round(rnorm(10, mean=3, sd = 1), 0)
x <- cbind(x1, x2, x3 = 0, x4 = NA)
x

x1 x2 x3 x4
1  2  0 NA
2  5  0 NA
3  2  0 NA
4  5  0 NA
5  3  0 NA
6  3  0 NA
7  2  0 NA
8  5  0 NA
9  3  0 NA
10  3  0 NA

xsub <- x[,apply(x, 2, function (x) !all(is.na(x)))] #excludes cols with all NAs
xsub <- xsub[,apply(xsub, 2, function(x) !all(x==0))] #excludes cols with all zeros
```

I've tried using | (or) in the function statement and nothing happens. Wrong syntax? Just learning about functions too.

```
xsub <- x[,apply(x, 2, function(x) !all(x==0) | !all(is.na(x)))]
```

I don't know how to use subset to call all columns with these values, just a column with a specific value.

Comment: @braaterAfrikaaner: Focus on the content of the question and provide a useful contribution. I chose the diction purposefully. This version no longer indicates that I've done my due diligence before posting, which is often a reason for closing a thread or soliciting snarky, unhelpful comments by the gallery.

Comment: my edit was approved by two moderators, confirming that it was useful. Saying that you read through other questions does not by itself indicate that you have done your due diligence, i.e. this phrase did not decrease the likelihood of your question being closed. This would only be useful if you could give more color on what you read and why it did not help. When in doubt, be concise.

Answer (score 0):

```
x[,which(colSums(x)>0)]
      x1 x2
 [1,]  1  3
 [2,]  2  4
 [3,]  3  3
 [4,]  4  4
 [5,]  5  3
 [6,]  6  4
 [7,]  7  2
 [8,]  8  4
 [9,]  9  4
[10,] 10  3
```

Comment: Thank you, Onyambu. I didn't think this would be a way to get rid of NAs too!

Comment: If this solves the problem, you can press on the tick checkmark to accept so that others may too benefit from it

Comment: Just tried it with my dataset and I got an error (Error in colsums(x) : 'x' must be numeric. Some of the columns are factors (with all NAs) and some are numeric (all zeros).

Comment: is that a matrix? Because a matrix will have only one type. Maybe you do have a dataframe. can you try `is.na(x)` and see whether it will give you `TRUE`? maybe the `NA` are characters.

Comment: It is a data frame. I get TRUE for the columns that have NA. The columns with all NAs have been identified as class "logical", not "character" in R. Some columns should be factor (an area code) and others should be integer (counts).

Comment: since you have various classes within your data, then you cannot use `colSums` as this deals with the only numeric and Integers. You may do `mapply(class,data)` to get an idea of the type of classes you have in you rdata

Answer (score 0):

Onyambu's solution works if the data frame is all numeric.

This one line of code worked for me.

```
xsub <- x[,apply(x, 2, function(x) !all(is.na(x)) & !all(x==0))]
```

The "&" processed like an inclusive "or" statement. 
It reads: In the data frame (x), take all columns (2) that are NOT all NAs (!all(is.na(x)) or NOT all zeros (!all(x==0). Hope this helps.

If you have a more elegant or simple solution, please post it.